# filter class names to make jquery array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to make array from class name that have no class name 'hidden':

```
<div id="part2">
<div class="address hidden">address</div>
<div class="floors">floors</div>
<div class="postcode"> </div>
<div class="city hidden"> </div>
</div>
```

i can go over the divs and make array as follows but i need only divs that have no class hidden-in this case only 'floors' and 'postcode'.

```
 var list_div_class = function() {
  var myarray = [];
  $('#part2').children().each(
      function(index) {
  var myclass = $(this).attr("class");
   myarray[index] = myclass;
        });
     return myarray;
    }

var arr_divs = list_div_class();
  alert (arr_divs);  // there is hidden listed but it's ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using `.map()` too

```
var arr = [];
arr = $('#part2').children().not('.hidden').map(function(i,e) {
    return $(e).attr('class');
}).get().join(', ');
```

### Result:

```
floors, postcode
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/EmBLP/1/)**

Comment: i think 'map' is most proper use in this case

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a selector in one line:

```
var arr_divs = $('#part2 div:not(".hidden")'); //this will be the array of divs without the class .hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Here is a working fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/n3Xjr/

```
var list_div_class = function() {
  var myarray = [];

  $('#part2').children().not('.hidden').each(function(index) {
    myarray[index] = $(this).attr("class");
  });

  return myarray;
}

var arr_divs = list_div_class();
alert(arr_divs);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so:

```
$(':not(.hidden)').each { ... }
```